# Python, MySQL regression, SQL bug or faulty conditionals?

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

I have a bucket folder that contains csv files of the form yy-mm-dd.CSV with several rows of header I can ignore apart from the date at the end of the second row, and then 151 rows of timestamp:power(kW). Here's a snippet:

```
    sep=;
    Version CSV|Tool SunnyBeam11|Linebreaks CR/LF|Delimiter semicolon|Decimalpoint point|Precision 3|Language en-UK|TZO=0|DST|2012.06.21

    ;SN: removed
    ;SB removed
    ;2120138796
    Time;Power
    HH:mm;kW
    00:10;0.000
    00:20;0.000
    00:30;0.000
    00:40;0.000
    00:50;0.000
    01:00;0.000
    01:10;0.000
    01:20;0.000
    01:30;0.000
    01:40;0.000
    01:50;0.000
    02:00;0.000
    02:10;0.000
    02:20;0.000
    02:30;0.000
    02:40;0.000
    02:50;0.000
    03:00;0.000
    03:10;0.000
    03:20;0.000
    03:30;0.000
    03:40;0.000
    03:50;0.000
    04:00;0.000
    04:10;0.000
    04:20;0.000
    04:30;0.000
    04:40;0.000
    04:50;0.006
    05:00;0.024
    05:10;0.006
    05:20;0.000
    05:30;0.030
    05:40;0.036
    05:50;0.042
    06:00;0.042
    06:10;0.042
    06:20;0.048
    06:30;0.060
    06:40;0.114
    06:50;0.132
    07:00;0.150
```

I parse the bucket folder for these files checking that they have this format filename, as there are other files I don't want to parse, and I grab the date from row two of each file and store it. I connect to the database and then work down the remaining lines, concatenating the stored date with the timestamp on each line after row 9 (or thereabouts). I also grab the second value on each line (power, in kW). The intention is to insert the concatenated date-time value and associated power value into the connected mysql database. When the last line is read, the file is moved to a subfolder, called 'parsed'. All of this proceeds as expected but every row read goes through the except branch of the try/except loop (Line 107) that prints 'cannot append to Db'. I've checked the stored database credentails work by logging in to MySQL (actually MariaDB on OpenSuse LEAP 4.2) and that works and I've printed the connection variable, both of which lead me to believe that I am actually connected properly for each file. I would snip out parts of my Python script to make it shorter but I'm not a particuarly advanced Python coder and I don't want to risk missing the key part:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

    from os import listdir
    from datetime import datetime
    import MySQLdb
    import shutil
    import syslog
    #from sys import argv


    def is_dated_csv(filename):
        """
        Return True if filename matches format YY-MM-DD.csv, otherwise False.
        """
        date_format = '%y-%m-%d.csv'

        try:
            date = datetime.strptime(filename, date_format)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            # filename did not match pattern
            syslog.syslog('SunnyData file ' + filename + ' did NOT match')
        #print filename + ' did NOT match'
            pass
    #'return' terminates a function
        return False


    def parse_for_date(filename):
    """
    Read file for the date - from line 2 field 10
    """
    currentFile = open(filename,'r')
    l1 = currentFile.readline() #ignore first line read
    date_line = currentFile.readline() #read second line
    dateLineArray = date_line.split("|")
    day_in_question = dateLineArray[-1]#save the last element (date)
    currentFile.close()
    return day_in_question


    def normalise_date_to_UTF(day_in_question):
    """
    Rather wierdly, some days use YYYY.MM.DD format & others use DD/MM/YYYY
    This function normalises either to UTC with a blank time (midnight)
    """
    if '.' in day_in_question: #it's YYYY.MM.DD
        dateArray = day_in_question.split(".")
        dt = (dateArray[0] +dateArray[1] + dateArray[2].rstrip() + '000000')
    elif '/' in day_in_question: #it's DD/MM/YYYY
        dateArray = day_in_question.split("/")
        dt = (dateArray[2].rstrip() + dateArray[1] + dateArray[0] + '000000')
    theDate = datetime.strptime(dt,'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    return theDate #A datetime object


    def parse_power_values(filename, theDate):
    currentFile = open(filename,'r')
    for i, line in enumerate(currentFile):
        if i <= 7:
        doingSomething = True
        print 'header' + str(i) + '/ ' + line.rstrip()
        elif ((i > 7) and (i <= 151)):
        lineParts = line.split(';')
        theTime = lineParts[0].split(':')
        theHour = theTime[0]
        theMin = theTime[1]
        timestamp = theDate.replace(hour=int(theHour),minute=int(theMin))
        power = lineParts[1].rstrip()
        if power == '-.---':
            power = 0.000
        if (float(power) > 0):
            print str(i) + '/ ' + str(timestamp) + '   power = ' + power + 'kWh'
            append_to_database(timestamp,power)
        else:
            print str(i) + '/ '
        elif i > 151:
        print str(timestamp) + ' DONE!'
        print '----------------------'
        break
    currentFile.close()

    def append_to_database(timestampval,powerval):
    host="localhost", # host
    user="removed", # username
    #passwd="******"
    passwd="removed"
    database_name = 'SunnyData'
    table_name = 'DTP'
    timestamp_column  = 'DT'
    power_column = 'PWR'
    #sqlInsert = ("INSERT INTO %s (%s,%s) VALUES('%s','%s')" % (table_name, timestamp_column, power_column, timestampval.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), powerval) )
    #sqlCheck = ("SELECT TOP 1 %s.%s FROM %s WHERE %s.%s = %s;" % (table_name, timestamp_column, table_name, table_name, timestamp_column, timestampval.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) )
    sqlInsert = ("INSERT INTO %s (%s,%s) VALUES('%s','%s')", (table_name, timestamp_column, power_column, timestampval.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), powerval) )
    sqlCheck = ("SELECT TOP 1 %s.%s FROM %s WHERE %s.%s = %s;", (table_name, timestamp_column, table_name, table_name, timestamp_column, timestampval.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) )
    cur = SD.cursor()
    try:
        #cur.execute(sqlCheck)
        # Aim here is to see if the datetime for the file has an existing entry in the database_name
        #If it does, do nothing, otherwise add the values to the datbase
        cur.execute(sqlCheck)
        if cur.fetchone() == "None":
            cur.execute(sqlInsert)
            print ""
        SD.commit()
    except:
        print 'DB append failed!'
        syslog.syslog('SunnyData DB append failed')
        SD.rollback()

    # Main start of program
    path = '/home/greg/currentGenerated/SBEAM/'
    destination = path + '/parsed'
    syslog.syslog('parsing SunnyData CSVs started')
    for filename in listdir(path):
    print filename
    if is_dated_csv(filename):
        #connect and disconnect once per CSV file - wasteful to reconnect for every line in def append_to_database(...)
        SD = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root",passwd="removed", db = 'SunnyData')
        print SD
        print filename + ' matched'
        day_in_question = parse_for_date(filename)
        print 'the date is ' + day_in_question
        theDate = normalise_date_to_UTF(day_in_question)
        parse_power_values(filename, theDate)
        SD.close()
        shutil.move(path + '/' + filename, destination)
        syslog.syslog('SunnyData file' + path + '/' + filename + 'parsed & moved to ' + destination)
```

It used to work but it's been a long time and many updates since I last checked it. I worry that a regression may have changed something under my code. Just not sure how to work it all out.

Apologies that this isn't a very crisp and specific question but if you can help me sort it, it may still serve as a good example for others?

Thanks

Greg

Comment: Consider catching exceptions: `except Exception as e: print(e)` instead of or in addition to `print 'DB append failed!'` as you will get actual MySQL / Mariadb or Python error messages.

Comment: I added your great suggestion and have better insight now. Turns out it's a type error
`argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not tuple`
Now just reading up what to do about it :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `SELECT TOP ...` syntax in MySQL/MariaDB, so your script must be failing upon trying to execute `sqlCheck`.

It should be `SELECT %s.%s FROM %s WHERE %s.%s = %s LIMIT 1` instead.

Comment: I changed my version to your version though it didn't make a difference. I'm sure you're right though, so, I'm leaving the edit in until I can feed the SQL a _string_, rather than a _tuple_ (who knew!?)